# How to push ViewController on full screen from modally presented ViewController with navigation controller iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, uimodalpresentationstyle

I have a situation where I have three viewcontroller let suppose VC1, VC2 and VC3, and I presented VC2 on VC1 modally with navigation controller like

```
   let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC2)
   self.present(nav, animation:true)
```

What I want push VC3 overfullscreen from VC2 without changing the Presentation style of VC2 in iOS 13+.
currently its overCurrentContext.

Answer (score 5):

If you are adding the view controller VC3 as the root view controller of a navigation controller, then you need to modalPresentationStyle as overFullScreen to the navigation controller.

```
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC3)
nav.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.present(nav, animation: true)
```

If you are directly presenting VC3, then do it like this.

```
VC3.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.present(VC3, animation: true)
```

Comment: Actually, what I want push not present VC3 overfullscreen from VC2 without changing the Presentation style of VC2.

Comment: VC pushed from VC2 will not take full screen mode. It will perform inside VC2 only. So you will have to present VC3 if you need to make it full screen.